# ASP.Net Core Api: how to deserialize a double-serialized JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, jsonconvert

I'm using a central API in ASP.Net Core to authenticate users and to create JSON Web Tokens. The central API, in turn, calls other APIs to get other data, such as user profile data and subscription information. However, the central API receives double-serialized JSON objects that I cannot seem to deserialize. Here's the code from the central API:

```
Request.Host = new HostString(_usersApi);

HttpRequestMessageFeature hreqmf = new HttpRequestMessageFeature(HttpContext);
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = hreqmf.HttpRequestMessage;

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, 
HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(data.Result);

return Ok(deserialized);
```

`data.Result` equals `"{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":\"value2\"}"`

I cannot deserialize it to

```json
{"Property1": "value1", "Property2": "value2"}
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you mix blocking (`data.Result`) and non-blocking (`await ... SendAsync()`) async calls?

Comment: Could you please share wit us your `MyObject` class definition?

Comment: Is that actually the value of the result, or is that just what Visual Studio is showing you when you debug? Strings in VS debug windows will be shown including C# escape characters by default, even though those characters aren't actually part of the string.

Comment: @PeterCsala As for mixing blocking and non-blocking calls, I did it merely for convenience. Do you advise against that?

Comment: @IMOsiris Always prefer await over .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: @PeterCsala MyObject is actually based on the class Google.Authenticator.SetupCode. Instead of using that class directly, I had to create a proxy with the properties, Account, ManualEntryKey, and QrCodeSetupImageUrl. Then everything worked properly.

Comment: If you have solved your problem then please leave a post and mark it as the answer.